# UINavigationBarItem custom - how to get the corner of tabcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i want to ask how i can get the icon of navigationtabbaritem to the left corner (left:0) and right corner (right:0).

my code :

```
_custombtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
_custombtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[_custombtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_msg.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_custombtn addTarget:self action:@selector(viewBn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.csbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:_custombtn];
```

[image: navigationitem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44, 44);
UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rightBarButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *spaceFix = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:NULL];
spaceFix.width = -10;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[spaceFix, aBarButtonItem];
```

Please add `spaceFix` for resolve your problem may this help lot